# Need help getting element out of URL in Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium, selenium-ide

Okay gang, this one's been a thorn in my side for far too long.

I have the following URL:
https://admin.test.com/modules/admin/listings/listingdetails.aspx?cid=94fbd84c-dd4a-4945-b049-aae7810b6057&action=Read

From this URL, I need to strip the CID value out and save it out as a variable for use in other Selenium scripts - specifically 94fbd84c-dd4a-4945-b049-aae7810b6057.

I've gotten Selenium to save out the URL easily enough as variable1, but getting the CID value is beyond my knowledge...I have NO programming experience.

Please help!  What I'm looking for is the specific Selenium instructions to get this to strip out properly.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: One way would be to find "CID=" and the next "&" and extract everything in between. What programming language would you be using?

Comment: Well right now I'm just using the Selenium IDE interface for all of my automation - but from what I read I can integrate javascript into that...although I'll have to figure out exactly HOW to do that!

Comment: Then you should use something like url.indexOf and url.substring.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.  It can be done by this. Paste this html code in the source tab.

```
<tr>
    <td>store</td>
    <td>https://admin.test.com/modules/admin/listings/listingdetails.aspx?cid=94fbd84c-dd4a-4945-b049-aae7810b6057&amp;action=Read</td><td>a</td></tr><tr><td>echo</td><td>${a}</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>storeEval</td><td>&quot;${a}&quot;.split(&quot;?&quot;)[1]</td><td>i</td></tr><tr><td>echo</td><td>${i}</td><td></td></tr><tr><td>storeEval</td><td>&quot;${i}&quot;.split(&quot;&amp;&quot;)[0]</td><td>g</td></tr><tr><td>echo</td><td>${g}</td><td></td></tr>
```